# Network Analyst: arcpy's 'Solve' running out of memory

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, network-analyst, error-030024

I've run [OD cost matrix analysis](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00470000004r000000) using GUI tools n ArcGIS 10.

My goal is relatively simple - find closest 50 neighbors for each origin point.

The dataset I'm working with is relatively large:

- network dataset consists of ~ 1.16 million elements
- there are ~ 100k origins
- and ~ 1.3 million destinations.

Origins are part of the destinations dataset.

The limits I set for the geoprocessing tool are: `default_number_destinations_to_find` set to 51 (since first 'neighbor' will be the same, overlapping point) and `default_cutoff` = 50000 (since I know from previous analyses that this value cannot be larger than that).

In order to save memory (I think) I go with `output_path_shape` set to `NO_LINES` - I do not need graphical representation of OD matrix - just tabular data (correct me if I'm wrong here).

It takes a while to process this task (~ 24h), but nonetheless I get the results.
So far so good.

In order to automate this task I tried putting all this steps into python script and came up with:

```
try:

    import arcpy
    from arcpy import env

    # Check out any necessary licenses
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")

    # set environment settings
    env.workspace = "D:\\GIS\\04-buildings.gdb"
    env.overwriteOutput = True

    # Local variables:
    NW_FIX_ND = "D:\\GIS\\02-network-restrict.gdb\\NW_FIX\\NW_FIX_ND"
    DESTINATIONS = "buildings\\destinations"
    ORIGINS = "buildings\\origins_1"
    OD_COST_MATRIX = "OD Cost Matrix"
    LINES = "OD Cost Matrix\\Lines"
    bn_1 = "results\\bn_1"

    # Make OD Cost Matrix Layer
    arcpy.MakeODCostMatrixLayer_na(NW_FIX_ND, "OD Cost Matrix", "Length", "50000", "51", "Length", "ALLOW_UTURNS", "restriction", "NO_HIERARCHY", "", "NO_LINES")

    # Add Destinations
    arcpy.AddLocations_na(OD_COST_MATRIX, "Destinations", DESTINATIONS, "Name h_gebaeude_id #;CurbApproach # 0", "5000 Meters", "", "TLM_STRASSE_RESTR_FIX SHAPE;NW_FIX_ND_Junctions NONE", "MATCH_TO_CLOSEST", "APPEND", "NO_SNAP", "5 Meters", "EXCLUDE", "TLM_STRASSE_RESTR_FIX #;NW_FIX_ND_Junctions #")

    # Add Origins
    arcpy.AddLocations_na(OD_COST_MATRIX, "Origins", ORIGINS, "Name h_gebaeude_id #;TargetDestinationCount # 51;CurbApproach # 0;Cutoff_Length # #", "5000 Meters", "", "TLM_STRASSE_RESTR_FIX SHAPE;NW_FIX_ND_Junctions NONE", "MATCH_TO_CLOSEST", "CLEAR", "NO_SNAP", "5 Meters", "EXCLUDE", "TLM_STRASSE_RESTR_FIX #;NW_FIX_ND_Junctions #")

    # Solve
    arcpy.Solve_na(OD_COST_MATRIX, "SKIP", "TERMINATE")

    # Select OD Lines
    arcpy.SelectData_management(OD_COST_MATRIX, "Lines")

    # Select
    arcpy.Select_analysis(LINES, bn_1, "")

    print "Completed successfully"

except Exception as e:

    # If an error occurred, print line number and error message
    import traceback, sys
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    print "An error occured on line %i" % tb.tb_lineno
    print str(e)
```

However, when I attempt to run this script I get the following **error**:

```
An error occured on line 39
ERROR 030024: Solve returned a failure.
Out of memory.
Failed to execute (Solve).
```

Why does arcpy fail when GUI could do the job?

My reasoning was that by running the task in python, and avoiding the graphical overhead, it should even work faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I've never managed to get to test @user27148 solution on ArcGIS 10.0.

Currently I'm working on the similar problem and can now confirm that with version 10.5 and 64-bit background geoprocessing [installed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243933/getting-64-bit-background-geoprocessing-running-in-arcgis-10-5) I was able to run very similar analysis on even larger files.

Before installation of 64-bit I was getting similar 'out of memory' error. Running Python script against 64-bit resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer is due to python.exe having a limit of about 2GB.

A solution is to [Set 32bit Executable LARGEADDRESSAWARE Flag to True](http://gisgeek.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/set-32bit-executable-largeaddressaware.html).