# Getting 64-bit background geoprocessing running in ArcGIS 10.5?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, arcgis-10.5, 64bit, background-geoprocessing

I've got fresh installation of ArcGIS 10.5 on my machine and was wondering from where and how can I get 64-bit background geoprocessing.

[Help pages](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/executing-tools/64bit-background.htm) are not explaining anything regarding installation.

In previous versions it was (I think) located on the installation media (similarly as pointed to in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80459/is-64-bit-background-geoprocessing-native-to-arcgis-10-2) or [this](https://geonet.esri.com/message/604164) questions for 10.2):

[image]

My IT department informed me that this is not the case any longer and in some newer [thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/169653) on geonet forum I found information that for version 10.3 this is downloadable from my.esri.com

[image]

(most likely with an institutional account..) but I cannot find any details regarding 10.5 version.

Has anyone managed to get and install it?

Comment: I can see it in the Downloads section of My Esri, the filename is `ArcGIS_Desktop_BackgroundGP_105_154031.exe`. You may just need someone in your organization to download it for you.

Comment: @DanC that with perhaps a screenshot sounds like it would make an answer

Comment: @DanC Thanks. I will find a person with institutional account at my Uni and will check that out.

Comment: For the record if you/they had downloaded the ISO image and burnt it to a DVD then you get the background 64 bit processing as an exe file to install, along with all the other files. It appears that install program that you show in your first screen shot does not exist anymore and you run each install exe individually rather than running them from a setup program. I guess ESRI had some reason to change their install workflow...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's downloadable for 10.5 as well, but you need to have access to the Downloads page for your organization on my.esri.com. Most likely, someone in your organization can either download it for you or they can grant you the ability to download it for yourself. I'm pretty sure I remember this download, and most other addons/patches for ArcGIS Desktop being freely accessible in the past (without signing in to an Esri account).

Here it is on my downloads page. The filename is `ArcGIS_Desktop_BackgroundGP_105_154031.exe`.

[image]