# Exporting large feature class to text file using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, export, csv, arcgis-10.5

I have a relatively large result file from [my network analysis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21376/network-analyst-arcpys-solve-running-out-of-memory) in ArcGIS 10.5. Data represents 100 closest neighbors for ~1.5 mio locations. The dataset is stored in a file geodatabase and it contains 'no geography' since I specified `NO_LINES` option in `MakeODCostMatrixLayer_na` tool so I treat it as a table.

I would like to move this data out of GIS for further processing in Stata (and or R). Since Stata is not GIS.. and I also wanted to avoid shapefile for data of this size I thought first about using txt or csv file as an intermediate way.

Learning from previous solutions, I tried three solutions:

1. Exporting via GUI in ArcCatalog
2. Exporting via ([64-bit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243933/getting-64-bit-background-geoprocessing-running-in-arcgis-10-5)) Python script with 'Export Feature Attribute to ASCII' (Spatial Statistics toolbox)
3. Exporting via Python script with 'Table To Table' (Conversion toolbox)
4. Exporting via Python script with 'Copy rows' (Data Management toolbox)
5. Exporting via Python script with a cursor loop (as suggested by Caleb1987 [here](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/61814#comment-290527))

Oddly enough, all these solutions give me a resulting file with 30 mio observations (exactly the same number) instead of 150 mio.

What can be causing a problem like that? Are there any better solutions for exporting files of this size?

Note: all scripts were tested with smaller datasets and everything worked smoothly so I am pretty confident there are no mistakes there.

---

Update: I managed to test one more solution via `ogr2ogr`. Using command line to connect to database and export to CSV:

```
ogr2ogr -f "CSV" "path\output.csv" "path\database.gdb" "feature_class"
```

This time I get to export 47mio records and the tool fails with many error messages similar to:

```
ERROR 1: Error occurred in filegdbtable.cpp at line 1284
```

Comment: Are you getting the first fifth of the records as your results?

Comment: @danak Yes these seem to be the 'top 20%' records from the result file

Comment: If you do Select All, does the selection count =record count? I have seen many database tools fail to search or select all the records when the count is extremely high.  You may have to break it up into a few batches.

Comment: How many rows are there in total? I belive there is a limit for the output rows 6553. try this: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f3d91b8f852042e289e09a7ec8342431

Comment: @danak When in table view in ArcCatalog I get correct number of features. `ogrinfo` returns the same value.

Comment: @Joe as described in question - there are 150mio rows in the table. What is `Excel and CSV Conversion Tools` using for reading/writing files?

Comment: @radek I am not sure what its using (assuming python) but I read it bypasses the output limit. give it a try and see if it works on a copy of the data. if not your going to have to break your data down into smaller chunks

Comment: Have you tested your theory that there may be a 30 million row limit to this export by dummying up 35 million rows and trying to export that?

Comment: You could try to read the feature class directly from R, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151613/how-to-read-feature-class-in-file-geodatabase-using-r

Comment: @Joe The tool you link to does not want to use as input feature classes nor tables from file gdb.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks - this is always an option and trying it now with some simple Python loop. Problem is - next time I can have few more variables and maybe it will be 20mio instead of 30.. So was trying to understand a reason of the failure on higher level. In a world of statistical software 150mio is not considered to be huge dataset that crashes software any longer. Was tad surprised that GIS trips on that o_O

Comment: @BERA Thaks for the pointer. I did try `ogr2ogr` from command line so I presume that kills this solution..

Comment: @radek I'll be surprised if there is a 30 million row limit - that's why I think you should test your assertion that there might be.

Comment: Are now you suspecting this to be a file geodatabase, ArcGIS Desktop and/or OGR limitation?  In any event I think you may be better to separate your ArcGIS and OGR investigations into separate questions.

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo. I run out of options and am now trying to work with smaller subsets of data and some loops. Not optimal solution but all works reasonably well so far with ~1/6 of the origins data. I'm not OGR expert and and don't have any other ideas so I think I'll refrain from starting new question.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://community.esri.com/thread/161827) thread the problem might be prevented by using the [arcgis excel and csv toolbox](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f3d91b8f852042e289e09a7ec8342431) . 
It can convert your table to csv, avoiding external max rows limitations.

Answer (score 0):

According to ArcGIS Desktop's [File geodatabase size and name limits](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/file-geodatabase-size-and-name-limits.htm) documentation you should not be getting close to its row number limitation:

> **Number of rows in a feature class or table**: 2,147,483,647

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo. Indeed it doesn't look like the 150 mio should be a limit. I think this is somehow confirmed by the fact that scripts creating this large file run without errors.. Similarly `ogrinfo` returns expected number of features. I understand that the issue is really in the export itself..

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Pandas which comes with ArcMap 10.5 installation:

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd

fc = r'C:\database.gdb\feature_class'

fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fields), columns=fields)

df.to_csv(path_or_buf=r'C:\folder\outfile.csv', sep=',')
```

Comment: Thanks @BERA. Have you managed to test this solution with such large dataset? I currently do not have access to the datasets that I struggled with when I asked this question so am not able to comment more.

Comment: No i have not. Should work if you have enough RAM to load all data into a pandas dataframe.